# Hibernate ignores constructor and setters

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I encountered an odd behavior when I tried to load some Objects from my Database using Hibernate 5.4.3.

Let's say I have a Class A which contains an instance of Class B. Now I want to load Class A from my Database but for some instances of A B is null. To prevent that there are A's with B's that are null I used the code below:

```
@Entity
public class A{

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private Long id;    

   @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   private B b = new B();

   public setB(B b){
       if(b == null){
           this.b = new B();
       }else{
           this.b =b;
       }
   }

   public B getB(){
       return this.b;
   }
}
```

Now when I use A's somehow I still get A's that have no instance of B. How is this possible?

Comment: You should use `@PostLoad` on an extra method which checks if `b` is null and if so create a new one

Comment: Depending on what you want you can also set B to be an Optional<B> and deal with it outside of you Entity if you need to.

Comment: I agree with @epsilonmajorquezero, the entity should reflect the exact state of your database, and the absence of B should be managed in the calling code.

Answer (score 1):

Well, business logic in getters / setters is at least dubious, especially if passing a `null` to a setter results in something as weird as a new blank object being assigned.

Hibernate doesn't need setters to build entities, it can do so with reflection. You can use [property access](https://thoughts-on-java.org/access-strategies-in-jpa-and-hibernate/), meaning setters are used, but for this use case I would not do that. Keep your getters / setters clean, and instead go for `@PostLoad` like XtremeBaumer suggested, or even better, keep them as nulls since that's what they are. I'd be terrified if my database nulls turned into some weird zombie objects on load.